# Cypress custom commands + Mochawesome reports: Log more details

Tags: cypress, mochawesome

**Goal: Add more details from Cypress custom commands to generated Mochawesome report**

I am new with Cypress.io and especially with Mochawesome report generation.

In creating cleaner code and avoid duplicity, I have added custom `Cypress.Commands`, for example

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />

Cypress.Commands.add('sandboxForceFailure', () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('ds_admin_base_url'));
    cy.url({ timeout: 1000 }).should('include', '/admin-dashboard');
});
```

The inconvenience I am currently experiencing with in using `Cypress.Commands` is that its granular Cypress calls made within a custom command are not included within the Mochawesome generated report.

This is an example of Cypress context with two tests, both performing the same test. First using direct `Cypress calls` and the second using the aforementioned custom `Cypress.Commands`:

```
context('Sandbox', () => {
   it('Force failure', () => {
      cy.visit(Cypress.env('ds_admin_base_url'));
      cy.url({ timeout: 1000 }).should('include', '/admin-dashboard');
   })

   it('Force failure Custom Command', () => {
      // @ts-ignore
      cy.sandboxForceFailure();
   })
})
```

Mochawesome report for **Test `'Force failure'`** shows that all Cypress calls performed in test:

```
'Force failure'
cy.visit(Cypress.env('ds_admin_base_url'));
cy.url({ timeout: 1000 }).should('include', '/admin-dashboard');
```

Mochawesome report for **Test `'Force failure Custom Command'`** shows that `cy.sandboxForceFailure()` was called, but nothing more...

```
'Force failure Custom Command'
// @ts-ignore
cy.sandboxForceFailure();
```

I would prefer if Test `'Force failure Custom Command'` shows Cypress calls performed within custom Cypress command, for example...

```
'Force failure Custom Command'
// @ts-ignore
cy.sandboxForceFailure();
-----
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('ds_admin_base_url'));
    cy.url({ timeout: 1000 }).should('include', '/admin-dashboard');
-----
```

Here are some additional details on Cypress.io configuration and NPM scripting in for generating Mochawesome report:

**File `cypress.json`**

```
    "reporter": "cypress-multi-reporters",
    "reporterOptions": {
        "reporterEnabled": "mochawesome",
        "mochawesomeReporterOptions": {
            "reportDir": "cypress/report/json",
            "overwrite": false,
            "html": false,
            "json": true,
            "timestamp": "mmddyyyy_HHMMss"
        }
    },
```

**File `package.json` scripts:**

```
    "cy:report:merge": "mochawesome-merge cypress/report/json/*.json > cypress/report/report_bundle.json",
    "cy:report:generate": "marge cypress/report/report_bundle.json --reportFilename report --charts true --reportDir cypress/report",
    "cy:report": "npm run cy:report:merge && npm run cy:report:generate",
```

Much appreciate any assistance. Is this level of report detail possible?

Comment: Did you have any joy in finding a solution to the above?? We are hitting almost exactly the same issue...

Comment: No, I have not found a solution. I am still using Mochawesome generated reports, but I am extending context using custom task in `cypress/plugins/index.js`.  `on('task', {
    log ($message) {
      if (typeof $message === 'string') {
        console.log($message)
      } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify($message, null, 2));
      }

      return null
    }
  })`